# How to set css in jQuery with multiple combinators

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some CSS that I need to change with jQuery. The css line looks like this:

```
.switch-vertical input ~ input:checked ~ .toggle-outside .toggle-inside {
  top: 40px;
}
```

So I tried the following:

```
$('.switch-vertical input ~ input:checked ~ .toggle-outside .toggle-inside').css('top', '20px');
```

But this does nothing, it also doesn't give an error. How can I set a line of CSS that looks like that?

I know best practice is to use classes but can it be done in another way?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in a “static” way, yes. But the expectation here probably is, that this applies dynamically, only when the checkbox is actually checked, and goes away again, once `input:checked` does not match any more. That would require manipulation of the actual CSS rule, not just overwriting of inline styles.

Comment: Reading the question again, you're right. I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I set a line of CSS that looks like that?

jQuery's `css` function doesn't create CSS rules. The `$` (`jQuery`) function you're passing the selector into looks for matching **elements** for that selector that exist in the DOM as of the moment you call that function. It returns a jQuery object (which is array-like, basically a set of elements). Then when you call `css` on it, it sets the inline style of each of those elements in the set to what you provide.

If you're not seeing anything happen when you run that code, it means that *as of when you ran that code*, no elements matched the selector (or changing the `top` on the ones that did wasn't visually apparent).

If you want to add a CSS rule so it applies to elements that exist now or ones added in the future, one way you can do that is to append a `style` element:

```
$("head").append(
    $("<style/>").text(
        ".switch-vertical input ~ input:checked ~ .toggle-outside .toggle-inside {\n" +
        "  top: 40px;\n" +
        "}"
    )
);
```

Live Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    $("head").append(
        $("<style/>").text(
            ".switch-vertical input ~ input:checked ~ .toggle-outside .toggle-inside {\n" +
            "  top: 40px;\n" +
            "}"
        )
    );
}, 800);
```

```html
<div class="switch-vertical">
  <input />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <div class="toggle-outside">
    <div class="toggle-inside" style="position: relative">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*(Note: I used [Rory McCrossan's HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286768/how-to-set-css-in-jquery-with-multiple-combinators/65286809#comment115419910_65286768) in the above, adding `position: relative` to the targeted element so you could see it move when the CSS was added.)*

> But this does nothing, it also doesn't give an error.

Correct. jQuery is set-based. Doing operations on an empty set isn't an error, it just means nothing happens. :-)